# webViewDidStartLoad method gets called multiple times

Tags: iphone, web

I have done the following:

*header file*

```
 UIWebView *itemWebView;
```

*implementation file*

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    itemWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    itemWebView.delegate = self;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:targetString];
    NSURLRequest *requestObject = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [itemWebView loadRequest:requestObject];
    [self.view addSubview:itemWebView];
    [itemWebView release];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)_webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (NSURLRequest *) request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSLog(@"ItemLoadinglViewController - shouldStartLoadWithRequest");

    loadingView.hidden = NO;
    itemWebView.hidden = YES;
    return YES;
}

- (void) webViewDidStartLoad: (UIWebView *) _webView {
    NSLog(@"ItemLoadinglViewController - webViewDidStartLoad");


}

- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad: (UIWebView *) _webView { 
    NSLog(@"ItemLoadinglViewController - webViewDidFinishLoad");

    loadingView.hidden = YES;
    itemWebView.hidden = NO;

}
```

Well this is how my `NSlog` looks like:

```
ItemLoadinglViewController - shouldStartLoadWithRequest
ItemLoadinglViewController - webViewDidStartLoad
ItemLoadinglViewController - shouldStartLoadWithRequest
ItemLoadinglViewController - shouldStartLoadWithRequest
ItemLoadinglViewController - webViewDidStartLoad
ItemLoadinglViewController - webViewDidFinishLoad
ItemLoadinglViewController - shouldStartLoadWithRequest
ItemLoadinglViewController - webViewDidStartLoad
ItemLoadinglViewController - shouldStartLoadWithRequest
ItemLoadinglViewController - webViewDidStartLoad
ItemLoadinglViewController - webViewDidFinishLoad
ItemLoadinglViewController - shouldStartLoadWithRequest
ItemLoadinglViewController - webViewDidStartLoad
ItemLoadinglViewController - webViewDidFinishLoad
ItemLoadinglViewController - shouldStartLoadWithRequest
ItemLoadinglViewController - webViewDidStartLoad
ItemLoadinglViewController - webViewDidFinishLoad
```

Has anyone any idea why these methods get called multiple times? I've used this before but each method was called only once.Why is different this time I can't figure out.Thanks:)

EDIT:

```
- (void) itemPressed:(id)sender{
    int x = [sender tag];

    ItemLoadingViewController *itemLoadingViewController = [[ItemLoadingViewController alloc] init];
    itemLoadingViewController.targetString = [target objectAtIndex:x];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:itemLoadingViewController animated:YES];
    [itemLoadingViewController release];
}
```

Comment: can you show how you load the view controller, it looks like view did load is called more then once.

Comment: also is it possible that your URL is using redirection? That could explain why the webview loads multiple time

Comment: I edited my question with the code.please look!

Comment: viewDidLoad gets called only once.I put a message and it was displayed only once!

Comment: are there redirections or multiple frame in the web page you're trying to load?

Comment: I assume yes.Then what is the solution to check when th webView was finally loaded for good?

Answer (score 1):

Move your initialization code from viewDidLoad to init & check.